# CSS img height with % not working

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

i'd like to resize an image (and the slider containing the image).

The following css code works fine:

```
.slick-slider .img-responsive{
  max-width:none;
  min-width:100%;
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

The object is achieved: the image/slider fills the whole width of the screen and takes only 300px of height. object-fit:cover crops the image.

But because i'd like to work responsive i want to change the height to a percentage value.

But if i replace 300px with 30% nothing happens (-> meaning the image has the full height, nothing is cropped).

[image: Relative value for height]

[image: Absolute value for height]

Comment: Viewport units might be a solution for your case.

Comment: Try using `auto` instead of `100%`

Comment: `auto` would respect the aspect ratio, I think OP doesn't want that.

Comment: yes i want to crop the image , auto won't work
i´ll have a look at the viewport units

Comment: percentage heights only work if the parent element has a height set. If that parent's height is also a percentage, then that will go back until either one of the ancestors has a absolute value, otherwise all ancestors up to and including the body and html tag need to have percentage heights set on them

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could you try this for me:

```
.slick-slider .img-responsive {
   min-width: 100vw;
   width: 100%;
   height: 10vh;
   object-fit: cover;
}
```

This forces your image to have a height of 10% of the **viewport** rather then pixels or percentages. It should create a responsive layout, let me know if it works out, and otherwise share a jsfiddle so I can poke around.

Comment: the result is exactly what i was looking for! thanks a lot!

Comment: I would suggest you'd put another class instead of .img-reponsive, since these rules defeat the semantic purpose of 'responsive images'

Comment: could you specify this a bit more? what do you mean that the purpose is defeated?

Comment: The class '.img-responsive' has the semantic value of A responsive image. With these properties, the responsiveness isn't there anymore. I'd say rename it into .header-img or so.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/semantic-class-names/ this has a lot of information about it.